# Creating a Dylib file using Swift or Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, dylib

Is it possible to create a .dylib file from a Objective-C or Swift coded-project, or must the code be written in C++?

I've seen several sources, but they're all written in C++.

see - [Creating and Using a Simple .dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405243/creating-and-using-a-simple-dylib)
and
[How do I create a dynamic library (dylib) with Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194485/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-library-dylib-with-xcode)

Is it even possible to create a .dylib file using any other language than c++?

Comment: That's possible at least for OS X. I use this approach in one my project. If you are interested in, I can prepare sample project to you.

Comment: if possible that would be great! @Melifaro

Comment: Ok then, give me 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed I have created an sample app for OS X. It uses dylib with single **Foo** Swift class. **Foo** has **doSomething** method, which logs kind of "hello world" message into the console.

Once you are built the project, you can find the dynamic library inside the application bundle in the Frameworks folder. It named **libFoo.dylib**.

Source code:
https://github.com/melifaro-/OSXDylibSample

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to call the dylib written by Swift from C++ code?